# Is there a better way to find an unknown with loops in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to "discover" what the `UNKNOWN` variable's value was when the `hash_res` was generated.

The only information that was given to me was that the following lines were used:

```
random.seed(UNKNOWN+hash(CONST_VAR))
hash_res = random.randint(1<<32, 1<<40)
```

Plus the value of `CONST_VAR` is a given which is `113092`.
The value of `RESULT_VAR` is also a given which is `75284812356`.

So far this is what I've came up with but I am not sure if this is the right way or of there is a faster, better way.

```
import random
from hashlib import md5

UNKNOWN = 0
CONST_VAR = 113092
RESULT_VAR = 75284812356
hash_res = 0

while hash_res != RESULT_VAR:
    UNKNOWN = UNKNOWN+1
    random.seed(UNKNOWN+hash(CONST_VAR))
    hash_res = random.randint(1<<32, 1<<40)

print UNKNOWN
```

Basically I am looping the given hashing lines then for every iteration, I'd increment the value of the `UNKNOWN` until the value of `hash_res` matches the `RESULT_VAR`. Then print out the value of the `UNKNOWN` when the loop terminates (a.k.a. `hash_res` has matched `RESULT_VAR`)

It's a brute force approach and my question is, is there a better way?

**NOTE:**
I am a c# developer, trying to learn something new :)

Comment: Trying to hack a Casino? :D

Comment: Nope! How I wish that was true @thefourtheye! This is an exercise given to me by a friend who uses python. I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: Maybe you can also use multi-threading (I just edited my answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's a brute force approach and my question is, is there a better way?

By all practical means for someone who is not a mathematical security/cryptography researcher, no.

The specification of a "hash" function is simply that it's a function that is nearly impossible to invert, i.e. brute forcing is the fastest way of reversing it.

There's a lot of tricks (rainbow tables, doing the math on a graphic card processor, or even a specialized chip etc) that make things faster, but aside from understanding the few weaknesses in MD5 and implementing this very close to the metal (read: probably C/C++, not python), there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 3):

> It's a brute force approach and my question is, is there a better way?

You can try to improve your brute force, by reducing the number of operation that you do at each loop cycle.

For instance, you can store `hash(CONST_VAR)`, `1<<32` and `1<<40` in variables.

You could also look at the source (as @tobias_k suggested), to find a quicker way to check if you have the right `UNKNOWN` (for instance using [`random.getstate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random.seed#random.seed) might be faster than `random.randint(1<<32, 1<<40)`)

I advise you to do some tests with a known `UNKOWN` to find the fastest algorithm.

---

**Edit**

maybe you could try to use parallelism with multiple thread looking for the value at the same time (with 4 threads, the first looks for 4*n, the second for 4*n+1, and so on)

Answer (score 1):

As per @tobias_k's suggestion to look at the source, I think this question boils down to, solving UNKNOWN in:

```
a = UNKNOWN+113092
a, x = divmod(a, 30268)
a, y = divmod(a, 30306)
a, z = divmod(a, 30322)
x, y, z = int(x)+1, int(y)+1, int(z)+1
x = (171 * x) % 30269
y = (172 * y) % 30307
z = (170 * z) % 30323
random = (x/30269.0 + y/30307.0 + z/30323.0) % 1.0

4294967296 + int(random * 2361183241434822606848) == 75284812356
```

Unfortunately you lose information every step of this algorithm which makes it almost impossible to reverse engineer.